# Java HTML Parsing not getting my data?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I have the following HTML code:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="first name">
      <a href="/quote/III:LN">3i Group PLC</a>
    </td>
    <td class="value">457.80</td>
    <td class="change up">+10.90</td>        <td class="delta up">+2.44%</td>        <td class="value">1,414,023</td>
    <td class="datetime">11:35:08</td>
```

For which I need to get the data

457.80

(ie. The value attribute), and I have this Java code currently:

```
String    FTSE    =            "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/UKX:IND/members";
    doc = Jsoup.connect(FTSE).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href='/quote/III:LN']");
    for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("value"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
```

When I run my program it terminates having output nothing. How do I make it so that it outputs the value, which in this case, is '457.80'?

Comment: I think that you're not using the correct selector. Instead of "a[href='/quote/III:LN']" try "td.value".

Answer (score 1):

`links` will contain the `<a href...>` element.  What you are trying to retrieve is the text of a completely different element, i.e. a `<td>` tag which has the class `value`.

My guess is that you have multiple `<tr>` elements and you only want the one which contains the link you've selected.  In which case you will need the following code:

```
String    FTSE    =            "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/UKX:IND/members";
doc = Jsoup.connect(FTSE).get();
Elements trs = doc.select("tr:has(a[href='/quote/III:LN'])");
Elements values = trs.select("td.value");
link = values.get(0);
System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
```

Or something similar...

Comment: Apologies for the nooby question, but I have a red line under link with the error 'link cannot be resolved to a variable', what do I do to resolve this?

Comment: Element link = values.get(0);